# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm getting this error in Laravel 8

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*)
```

This is how I'm trying to do the query

```
$totalCitasGenero = DB::table('citas')->selectRaw('idEspecialidad, genero,  count (*) as totalCitas')->join('personas', 'personas.id', '=', 'citas.idPersonaP')->groupBy('idEspecialidad','genero')->get();
```

This is how my tables looks like

```
CREATE TABLE `personas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cedula` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ciudadResi` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `fechaNacimiento` date NOT NULL,
  `genero` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `estado` binary(1) NOT NULL,
  `idTipoPersona` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idPersona` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `personas_FK` (`idTipoPersona`),
  KEY `personas_FK_1` (`idPersona`),
  CONSTRAINT `personas_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`idTipoPersona`) REFERENCES `tipo_personas` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `personas_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idPersona`) REFERENCES `personas` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=73 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

CREATE TABLE `citas` (
  `idPersonaD` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idPersonaP` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `hora` time NOT NULL,
  `idEspecialidad` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `estado` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `citas_FK` (`idPersonaD`),
  KEY `citas_FK_1` (`idPersonaP`),
  KEY `citas_FK_2` (`idEspecialidad`),
  CONSTRAINT `citas_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`idPersonaD`) REFERENCES `personas` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `citas_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idPersonaP`) REFERENCES `personas` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `citas_FK_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idEspecialidad`) REFERENCES `especialidades` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=88 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

on DBeaver the query works fine and this is how it looks like

```
select idEspecialidad, genero,  count (*) as totalCitas 
from citas as c join personas
where c.idPersonaP = personas.id 
group by genero, idEspecialidad ;
```

The results I'm expecting are the ones in the picture below.

[image: results I expect]

What is wrong translating the query into Laravel?

if I do a dd of the variable after I switch the ->get() as toSql() ->as suggested I get this result

```
"select idEspecialidad, genero,  count (*) as totalCitas from `citas` inner join `personas` on `personas`.`id` = `citas`.`idPersonaP` group by `idEspecialidad`, `genero`
```

I have even tried coppying the query into DBeaver again and it works fine, its just in Laravel that isnt working not sure why.

The query looks fine so I have no idea why it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Please share your query output by replacing the `->get()` with `->toSql()`

Comment: ok I would do it right now

Comment: I do a dd() to show the value of the variable and it is this "select idEspecialidad, genero,  count (*) as totalCitas from `citas` inner join `personas` on `personas`.`id` = `citas`.`idPersonaP` group by `idEspecialidad`, `genero`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the white space that you have in `count (*)`

```
$totalCitasGenero = DB::table('citas')->selectRaw('idEspecialidad, genero,  count(*) as totalCitas')->join('personas', 'personas.id', '=', 'citas.idPersonaP')->groupBy('idEspecialidad','genero')->get();
```

Comment: ok I will try that

Comment: thanks, it worked. You saved my life